# How to get subclasses attributes using SingleTableInheritance with SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, inheritance

i am working on a web application using Spring, Hibernate and SpringMVC,
i am facing a problem with retreiving values from a subclass table using SingleTable inheritance strategy, here are my entities

Client.java (Super class)

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "typeClient", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    public class Client implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int idClient;

        private String matricule;
        private String statut;

        private String secteurDactivite;
        private String nomClient;


        private String emailClient;

        private String numTelephone;

        private String adresse;
//constructor
//getter & setters
     }
```

Societe.java  (subClass1)

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Societe")
public class Societe extends Client implements Serializable{


    private String nomResponsable;


    private String emailResponsable;


    private String telResponsable;


    private String nomSuperieur;


    private String emailSuperieur;


    private String telSuperieur;

    private String commentaire;

    //constructeur sans parametre
    public Societe() {
        }
    }
```

Particulier.java (subclass2)

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Particulier")
public class Particulier extends Client implements Serializable {

    private String cin;


    //constructeur sans parametres
    public Particulier() {

    }
    }
```

in my implementation i am using this methode to get a particular client with his ID

ClientDaoImpl.java

```
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Client getClientByID(int id_client) {
        return em.find(Client.class, id_client);
    }
```

When i ran this code i only selected the attributes of the superClass **Client**.

what i am trying to do is to get a client with its subclass whether it's a **Societe** or **Particulier** based on its type or clientID.

Please Help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't know the type of client before querying and only it's ID, you will need to inspect the type and cast after you retrieve the record;

```
Client client1 = clientDao.getClientById(clientID);
if (client1 instanceof Societe) {
    ((Societe) client1).getCommentaire();
}
```

Depending on your use case, it may be useful to map the result of the client query to a ClientDescriptor object which contains all the fields for all client types and returns either nulls or blanks.  This means you don't have to keep checking for client type everywhere;

```
public class ClientDTO {
    //client fields
    private String nomResponsable = "";
    ....
    //subclass 1 fields.... initialize to empty
    //subclass 2 fields .... initialize to empty

    public ClientDTO (Client client) {
        // set fields for client entity
    }

    public ClientDTO (Societe societe) {
        this (societe);
        // set societe fields.
    }
    // other constructors.
}
```

Comment: That is a nice approach as well, just a minor suggestion, I would replace `equals` with `instanceof` or even `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it"s working fine, i didn't think about it, it's simple :D, i appreciate it GrumpyWelshGit you saed the day.

Comment: Happy to help! @BohdanLevchenko thanks for the suggestion, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your getClientByID method to accept an additional argument which will say what type of entity your want to retrieve and get back:

```
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public <T extends Client> T getByID(int id_client, Class<T> klass) {
        return em.find(klass, id_client);
    }
}
```

And you can use this dao in the following manner:

```
Societe societe = clientDao.getByID(42, Societe.class);
Particulier particulier = clientDao.getByID(43, Particulier.class);
```

Comment: This is an excellent generic solution, but you do need to know the type in advance of the query.

Comment: @GrumpyWelshGit, true, but it is the most likely caller will know an actual type upfront.